# How to implement authorize function from next-auth in next 13 appDir (typescript)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, next-auth

What is the correct way to declare the `authorize` function in `[...nextauth].ts`??
I'm tryin it like this:

```js
 export default NextAuth({
        session: {
                strategy: "jwt"
        },
        providers:[CredentialsProvider({
                async authorize(credentials:Record<string,string>){
                        dbConnect()
                        const {email,password} = credentials as {
                                email: string,
                                password: string,
                              };;      
                        const user = await User.findOne({ email: email})
                        if(!user){
                                throw new Error("Invalid email or password")
                        }
                        const isPasswordMatched = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password )
                        if(!isPasswordMatched){
                                throw new Error("Invalid email or password")
                        }
                        return user;

                }
        })]

})
```

but  authorize is highlighting error which is:

```bash
Type '(credentials: Record<string, string>) => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Record<string, string> | undefined, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">) => Awaitable<User | null>'.
  Types of parameters 'credentials' and 'credentials' are incompatible.
    Type 'Record<string, string> | undefined' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.
      Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, string>'.ts(2322)
credentials.d.ts(13, 5): The expected type comes from property 'authorize' which is declared here on type 'UserCredentialsConfig<Record<string, CredentialInput>>'
```

what does that mean??

Comment: remove this line credentials:Record<string,string>  &  add this credentials:object, req or  name: "Credentials"

Comment: `
 async authorize(credentials:object,req:"Credentials"){
....}
`
Now doing like this but still giving the error:

Comment: Type '(credentials: object, req: "Credentials") => Promise<any>' is not assignable to type '(credentials: Record<string, string> | undefined, req: Pick<RequestInternal, "body" | "query" | "headers" | "method">) => Awaitable<User | null>'.

Comment: authorize: async (credentials: object, req)

Comment: still authorize is red underlined! :(

Comment: In  **tsconfig.json **  (strict" :false ) check it is strict false or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254421/discussion-between-naeemgg-and-naveen-nizam).

Answer (score 0):

**tsconfig.json** ("strict": false )

no more restrictions to your code. The below link helps you to understand **strict mode**

https://dev.to/jsdev/strict-mode-typescript-j8p